# Join columns of Day, Month , Year to calculate age

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

```
public function patients_view($id)
{
    $patient =  Patients::where('id', '=', $id)->first();

    // ....
}
```

I just need to view the age. Thanks , im using blade.php btw

Comment: Can you alter schema? That date set up is going to cause issues down the road. It is much easier to use a `date` data type then extract any value from that via `MONTHNAME()`, `YEAR()`, or `DAY()` that is needed.

Comment: i actually have dropdowns for month, day and year. since the target user doesnt want the calendar view, and its the reason why i separated the columns instead of one

Comment: Separating the fields is good practice for gathering user input, but joining them together into a single DATE type in the database is virtually always going to be beneficial.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @ruleboy21 im using 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [*"Accessor"*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) to get the age.

- Define a `getAgeAttribute` method that calculate the age in the
  `Patients` model
- Append the method to the model

```
class Patients extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['age'];

    /**
     * Get the patients's age.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAgeAttribute($value)
    {
        $age = (time() - strtotime($this->dobDay.' '.$this->dobMonth.' '. $this->dobYear)) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
        $age = floor($age);

        return $age;
    }
}
```

And use it like so

```
public function patients_view($id)
{
    $patient =  Patients::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
    dd($patient->age);
    // ....
}
```